# Activate UserForm with only one 'Enter'

Tags: vba, excel

I want to start up the UserForm with ONLY pressing on a number and on Enter (so no clicking involved). The problem I have is with pressing Enter twice. What happens if I press Enter the first time is it focuses on `Doorgaan` and after the second Enter it actually 'clicks' `Doorgaan`.

[image: How it looks]

Does anyone know how I can change this to one enter?

Comment: if you have just a single-digit number to enter use the`KeyUp` event on the TextBox to set the focus onto the `Doorgaan` command button, then all you to do is hit Enter once on the `'Doorgaan` button.

Comment: Does Excel have ```GotFocus event```? [Access has](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff822451.aspx). If yes, then handle this event and try to execute click-event handler of the button, might it be possible?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Too bad it has to be multi-digits so that won't work.

Comment: @dee It does have a GotFocus event but i can't seem to find an execute click event. I tried this but didn't work : " Private Sub btnBestellen_GotFocus()
    Me.btnBestellen.MouseUp
End Sub"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `Doorgaan` to `Default` within the `properties` in the VBE. There is only **one** element per form that can be `default`. The default element will be activated upon pressing `Enter`. So, if you set that button to `Default = True` then the code for that button will run when you press enter.

You can also change the element which is `Default` during runtime like so:

```
UserForm1.btnDoorgaan.Default = True
```

By the way, there is also the option to set an element to `Cancel = True`. That element gets activated when you hit `Escape` on the key board. So, if you add a `Cancel` button to your form and assign it to `Cancel = True` then you can easily close and exit that form by just pressing `Escape`.

Answer (score 3):

Ralph's solution is the easiest way to implement it if you have a simple form like yours

If you have multiple buttons, or use labels instead of buttons you can do something like this

```
Private Sub TxtBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then Me.Hide    'or CommandButton1_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is evident to everybody. So, I would like to elaborate on this solution: (a) your solution captures only the `Enter` key when pressed in that particular text box while my solution captures the `Enter` key whenever pressed **anywhere** within this form and (b) that your solution could be expanded upon to caputre ALT+s or ALT+t to "press" other buttons on more complex forms. The solution I am showing above is merely the simple solution as intended by Microsoft for the `Enter` key and the `Escape` key. All other keys (or combinations) can be captured using this solution.