# Excel VBA UserForm Closing by ESC Key

Tags: excel, hotkeys, vba

We can use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to close most of the built-in dialog boxes in Excel, and most other applications.

How can we assign the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to close an Excel VBA UserForm?

Comment: If you have a Command Button to unload the form you can change it's `Cancel` property to `True`.

Comment: Check the answer of `Jesus` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240677/close-userform-with-escape-button And my comment below it! :)

Comment: Or check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244626/activate-userform-with-only-one-enter/33246450#33246450

Comment: Thanks to all, that solved my problem.